# python GLM Poisson regression diverges in hand-coded implementation

Tags: python-3.x, poisson, newtons-method

I'm having trouble with convergence of this [R-code](https://rpubs.com/enwuliu/1011024) translated to Python: **statsmodels.GLM** gives correct result

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import expit   # overflow encountered in exp
import statsmodels.api as sm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# data
y= np.array([2,3,6,7,8,9,10,12,15],  dtype = np.float)
x= np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],  dtype = np.float).reshape(2,9).T    # with intercept in 1st col
data= pd.DataFrame({"y": y, "intercept": x[:,0], "x": x[:,1]})
print(data)

# for glm function
x1= np.array([-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],  dtype = np.float)
_x1 = sm.add_constant(x1, prepend=False)
_y = y[:, np.newaxis]

########################
## GLM
#######################
# implement-poisson-regression
from statsmodels.genmod.cov_struct import (Exchangeable, Independence,Autoregressive)
from statsmodels.genmod.families import Poisson

ind= ind = Independence()
fam= sm.families.links.log()    ## Log-Linear Regression, also known as Poisson Regression

##data.endog DV, data.exog IV
poisson_model = sm.GLM(  _y, _x1, cov_struct=ind, family = Poisson(link= fam))
poisson_results = poisson_model.fit( atol=1e-8)     # attach_wls=True,
print(poisson_results.summary())
##print(poisson_results.params)

###########
# https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html
# Plot yhat vs y:
from statsmodels.graphics.api import abline_plot

yhat = poisson_results.mu
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(yhat, _y)
line_fit = sm.OLS(_y, sm.add_constant(yhat, prepend=True)).fit()
abline_plot(model_results=line_fit, ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Model Fit Plot')
ax.set_ylabel('Observed values')
ax.set_xlabel('Fitted values');
plt.show()
```

**sklearn** gives different `betas` - is the problem in [log_scaling_preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_poisson_regression_non_normal_loss.html#generalized-linear-models) because of the nature of [lambda param](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453150) ? still cannot achieve correct *coef=0.6698  & intercept=1.8893*

```
#######################
## SKLEARN
#######################
from sklearn import linear_model

regr = linear_model.PoissonRegressor(tol= 1e-8)
regr.fit(data[[ "x"]], data.y)

print("\nPoissonRegressor")
print(regr.score(data[[ "x"]], data.y))
print("coef_ ", regr.coef_)
print("intercept_ ", regr.intercept_)
```

but the main problem from the above-linked article is **hand-coded Newton-Raphson algorithm** , as it seems to diverge, not converge, though being coded like in linked R-code -- where is my mistake in translating the logics to Python ?? Whether `w`_matrix should be calculated in [the other way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598116/covariance-matrix-of-linear-estimator-of-basis/598118#598118) ?

```
def poisson_Newton_Raphson(x,y,b_init,tol=1e-8):
  change = np.inf
  b_old = b_init
  while(change > tol) :
    eta = x @ b_old  # linear predictor
    w = np.diag(expit(eta))
    temp = x.T @ w @ x         # ?? np.linalg.inv(x.T @ w @ x)
    b_new = b_old + (temp @ x.T @ (y-expit(eta)))
    change= np.linalg.norm(b_old - b_new, 2)
##    print(change)
    b_old = b_new
    print(b_old)
  return b_new

res= poisson_Newton_Raphson(x, y, np.zeros(2))
print(res)
```

how to make all 3 codes give the same results ?? (correct in GLM_example)

P.S. [alternative](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring21/sta440.001/slides/glm-2.html#9) -- anyway, my `w`-matrix seems to be errorness - how to correct it ?

P.P.S. [Poisson Regression](https://bookdown.org/roback/bookdown-BeyondMLR/ch-poissonreg.html) to model either [counts or frequencies](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430001/poisson-regression-with-offset-vs-poisson-regression-with-weight),   e.g. [for a non-constant λ](https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/poisson-regression-model/), Poisson distribution has its [variance equal to its mean](https://www.statology.org/poisson-regression/), as lambda grows large the Poisson looks more and more like a normal distribution, to [interpret](https://tidypython.com/poisson-regression-in-python/)

P.P.P.S. [glm-Course_001](https://statmath.wu.ac.at/courses/heather_turner/glmCourse_001.pdf), n.b. [choice of distribution](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#generalized-linear-models)

Comment: for `sklearn` solution - `alpha=0` is helpful here anyway. Thanks to *Onyambu's* solution in his answer.

Comment: [IRLS for GLM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/412674/347139) described as "each iteration just comes down to doing a weighted least squares regression with 1/variance weights" (for any certain kind of distribution)

Comment: additionally, can use [HistGradientBoostingRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_time_series_lagged_features.html#proper-next-hour-forecasting-evaluation) with *poisson*-loss

Comment: off: [Gradient Descent vs. Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798195/would-newtons-method-classify-as-a-gradient-descent-method?rq=1)

Comment: P.S. overall, [CONTENT_ A Guide For Engineers And Scientists](https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/Index.html) -- Newton for root_finding (often locally), GD just optimizing/minimizing to certain/ (any chosen) direction ...

Comment: P.P.S. [Improving the condition number of estimated covariance matrices](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/16000870.2019.1696646), 17 [Condition number regularization](https://bochang.me/gmrg/files/Bo_05292015.pdf) or [here](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/75/3/427/7075419) - Condition-Number-Regularized Covariance Estimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods you listed give exactly the same results. Here is a display:

```
x = np.array([ 1.,-1,1,-1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]).reshape(-1,2)
y = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0])
 
def poisson_Newton_Raphson(x, y, b_init, tol = 1e-8):
   change =  1
   b = np.array(b_init) + 0.0
   while change > tol:
     eta = x @ b  # linear predictor
     w = np.diag(np.exp(eta))
     direction = np.linalg.solve(x.T @ w @ x, x.T @ (y - np.exp(eta)))
     change = np.linalg.norm(direction)
     b += direction 
   return b

poisson_Newton_Raphson(x,y,[1,1])
array([1.889272 , 0.6697856])
```

---

```
from sklearn.linear_model import PoissonRegressor
regr = PoissonRegressor(fit_intercept = False, tol = 1e-8, alpha = 0)
regr.fit(x, y).coef_
array([1.88927199, 0.66978561])
```

---

```
from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import Poisson
Poisson(y, x).fit(disp = 0).params
array([1.889272 , 0.6697856])
```

---

```
def poisson_IRLS(x, y, b_init, tol=1e-8):
  change = np.Inf
  b = np.array(b_init) + 0.0
  while change > tol:
    eta = x @ b
    weight = np.exp(eta)
    w = np.diag(weight)
    z = np.linalg.solve(w, y - weight)
    direction = np.linalg.solve( x.T @ w @ x, x.T @ w @ z)
    change = np.linalg.norm(direction)
    b += direction
  return b

poisson_IRLS(x,y,[1,1])
array([1.889272 , 0.6697856])
```

Comment: really, I was confused about doing np.linalg.solve() in the right way. Thank you very much! I will study your examples thoroughly!с

Comment: if you will have some more time & additional desire to complete the topic - could you, please, check/correct implementation with `scipy.optimize.minimize` I'm posting below -- yet not fully solved ...

Comment: @JeeyCi what do you mean by not fully solved? Note that for MLE, you aim at maximizing and not minimizing. So you should have negative log like for minimization

Comment: PERFECT !  `def opt_prob(b, X, y): return -1* loglik(b, X, y), -1* gradloglik(b, X, y)` gives exactly `x: array([1.88927399, 0.66978528])` - your advice is what I needed for the rest of the day !

Comment: concerning solution with *Normal_Equation*, really "when we have to do `np.linalg.inv` we'd better prefer `np.linalg.solve` " for computational precision & speed reasons

Comment: and really, W(t) is the [diagonal matrix of weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares)

Answer (score 0):

another hand-coded **Newton-Raphson** [implementation](https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1186659/python-glm-poisson-regression-convergence) with `scipy.optimize.minimize` - was not working, but corrections advised above by *Onyambu* did it working as well

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import scipy.special

# data
x = np.array([ 1.,-1,1,-1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]).reshape(-1,2)
y = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 12.0, 15.0])

########################

# Define the log-likelihood function
def loglik(b, X, y):
    expb = np.exp(np.dot(X, b))
    # print(expb)
    ret = np.sum(y * np.log(expb) - expb - np.log(scipy.special.factorial(y)))
    return ret

# Define the gradient of the log-likelihood function
def gradloglik(b, X, y):
    expb = np.exp(np.dot(X, b))
    ret = np.dot(X.T, (y - expb))
    # print(r)
    return ret

# Define the optimization problem
def opt_prob(b, X, y):
    return -1* loglik(b, X, y), -1* gradloglik(b, X, y)

# Set the initial values for the coefficients
##print(X.shape[1])
b0 = np.zeros(x.shape[1])

# Optimize the log-likelihood function
result = minimize(opt_prob, b0, args=(x, y), method='BFGS', tol=1.4e-08, jac=True)


# Extract the optimized coefficients
coef = result.x
print(coef)
```

Comment: [derivation with numdifftools](https://rh8liuqy.github.io/Newton_Raphson.html) used for Poisson regression - seems still problematic for me, but  worth mentioning... testing needed

Comment: one more [manual derivation](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring21/sta440.001/slides/glm-2.html#8)...  will also try to test... (my attempts still have some bugs in testing here mentioned codes)

Comment: in first case, `numdifftools.Derivative` hidden the implementation, thus making questionable the possibility to use this method for multidimensional X & correctness of its return_vars

Comment: in second case, the problem was already mentioned above:  substitution of `np.linalg.inv` with `np.linalg.solve` is needed -- should be ok

Comment: [numpy second derivative of a ndimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206443/numpy-second-derivative-of-a-ndimensional-array)

Comment: really, `log_likelihood_hessian` is being calculated with `np.diag(predictions * (1 - predictions))` [e.g. here for logistic regression](https://ee227c.github.io/code/lecture24.html)

Comment: off: [manual IRLS for logistic regression](http://www.nicksun.fun/statistics/2023/03/01/IRLS-from-scratch.html) in R

Comment: off: [1.2 Confidence intervals on the parameters](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/f19-06623/18-linear-regression.html) for linear regression

Comment: [newton](https://github.com/mkozturk/notebooks/blob/master/Rosenbrock%2C%20Newton's%20method.ipynb) with `p = p - np.linalg.solve(hess,grad)`